# Discord.js Bot slash commands do not respond

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a discord.js bot that monitors a server and notifies users when another user starts to play a specific game. I want to add some slash commands but for some reason they always fail without any error but the warning message "The application did not respond".

I chose to start testing with the basic ping slash command:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        try {
            await interaction.reply('Pong!');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('An error occurred:', error);
            await interaction.reply('An error occurred while processing your command.');
        }
    },
};
```

Here is my deploy command:

```
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('node:fs');

const commands = [];
// Grab all the command files from the commands directory you created earlier
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

// Grab the SlashCommandBuilder#toJSON() output of each command's data for deployment
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

// Construct and prepare an instance of the REST module
const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(token);

// and deploy your commands!
(async () => {
    try {
        console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length} application (/) commands.`);

        // The put method is used to fully refresh all commands in the guild with the current set
        const data = await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} application (/) commands.`);
    } catch (error) {
        // And of course, make sure you catch and log any errors!
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

The ping slash command is indeed inside the `/commands` folder.

I have tried the following troubleshooting ideas:

1.) I am using the correct `/ping` prefix.

2.) I have verified that the bot is running on the appropriate server.

3.) Checked for server specific issues which I found none.

4.) The bot token is correct.

5.) Tried it in a different channel

6.) The bot has administrator permissions

7.) I have run `node deploy-commands.js`

What more needs done to be able to use slash commands?

If you need to see the whole project it is here: https://github.com/ZoeyOneOhOne/Halo-Notifier-Bot

It's important to note that the primary functionality of the bot all happens in index.js and works perfectly. Only slash commands do not work.

Comment: You don't have an `interactionCreate` event! Your commands won't respond unless you listen to interactions.